# Installing Docker CE in redhat

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have tried to install Docker CE in my system and it ends with some problem.

I did the below steps:

1. sudo yum install -y yum-utils – No error
2. sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo
   https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo - No error
3. sudo yum makecache fast – No error
4. sudo yum -y install docker-ce – Failed with error

Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9

---

yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf

---

Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: Try install it this way `curl -SsL https://get.docker.com | sh` and see if it works

Comment: Thanks Tarun for your replay. curl -SsL https://get.docker.com | sh It didn't worked for me

Comment: Which version of Redhat do you have?

Comment: it was looking for the decency package `container-selinux `. do you have older version installed on our machine. run `rpm -qa |grep container-selinux ` command see the output

Comment: see this thread and check you have centos version of docker installed. https://forums.docker.com/t/centos7-installation-error-docker-engine-selinux-conflicts-with-2-container-selinux-1-10-3-59-el7-centos-x86-64/27003

Comment: Tarun this is the version 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: rpm -qa |grep container-selinux - No results when running this..

Comment: The issue have been fixed now : sudo yum install container-selinux, ran this before installation

Answer (score 1):

The `container-selinux` package is available from the `rhel-7-server-extras-rpms` channel. You can enable it using:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
```

But if you do not have any subscription for Enterprise Linux, you can use CentOS Extra repo as a workaround. Add the below content into `/etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo`

```
[CentOS-extras]
name=CentOS-7-Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```