# Docker installation on AWS EC2 (RHEL) is not working

Tags: ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2, centos, rhel

I am attempting to install Docker on an AWS EC2 instance that has RHEL 7.3. I get - 
ec2-user@ip-172-31-14-68:~$ sudo yum install -y docker
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do

I then looked up on the website and found that Docker Community Edition is not supported on RHEL. 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ee/rhel/

What OS is it supported on ? Ubuntu, CentOS ?

Thanks

Comment: I just installed docker-ce on Ubuntu with no problems.

Comment: Thanks! Have you tried it with RHEL ? Any success ?

Comment: As you said the docs indicate that CE is not available.  I was unable to get the CE edition working on a fresh RHEL install.

Comment: @stdunbar Thanks for confirming

Comment: Here is the link for platforms docker supported, https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/#cloud Yes. we can not install docker-ce on RHEL versions. And, you could directly go for AWS ECS(EC2 Container Service)

Answer (score 1):

For RHEL 7.x, docker exists in the `rhel-7-server-extras-rpms` repository. If your subscription has the appropriate entitlements, you can use the following command to enable the repository.

```
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
```

If successful, you should be able to install the `docker` package.

Answer (score 0):

And in continuation of the answer given by @Dave.

If you do not have a subscription to RHEL packages you can use CentOS Extras repo and continue with your installation. I have already answered a very similar question. Please refer to that.
[Installing Docker CE in redhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415524/installing-docker-ce-in-redhat/47903707#47903707)

Answer (score 0):

Use below command for ec2 redhat instances and then run yum install docker

$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras